# Unity Ai GameObject Keeping increasing his speed when he moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i did some code making an enemy search if the player exists or not and if the player exists go-to player to kill him the code is working fine but every moment the enemy move the speed keep increased and i do not want the speed increased at all so how to make it moving at the same starting speed without any increase 
this is my code

```
void Update () {
    if (target == null) {
        if (!searchingForThePlayer) {
            searchingForThePlayer = true;
            StartCoroutine (searchForPlayer ());
        }
        return;
    }

    if (Vector3.Distance (target.position, transform.position) < 20) {

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, target.position, 1f * Time.deltaTime);
        if (target.position.x < transform.position.x && !facingRight) 
            Flip ();
        if (target.position.x > transform.position.x && facingRight)
            Flip ();

    } else {

    }

    StartCoroutine (UpdatePath ());
}
IEnumerator searchForPlayer () {
    GameObject sRusult = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
    if (sRusult == null) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
        StartCoroutine (searchForPlayer ());
    } else {
        target = sRusult.transform;
        searchingForThePlayer = false;
        StartCoroutine (UpdatePath ());
        yield return null;
    }

}
IEnumerator UpdatePath () {
    if (target == null) {
        if (!searchingForThePlayer) {
            searchingForThePlayer = true;
            StartCoroutine (searchForPlayer ());
        }
        yield return null;
    } else {
        if (Vector3.Distance (target.position, transform.position) < 20) {

            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, target.position, 1f * Time.deltaTime);
            if (target.position.x < transform.position.x && !facingRight)
                Flip ();
            if (target.position.x > transform.position.x && facingRight)
                Flip ();

        } else {

        }
    }
    // Start a new path to the target position, return the result to the OnPathComplete method

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f / 2f);
    StartCoroutine (UpdatePath ());
}

void Flip () {
    Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
    scale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = scale;
    facingRight = !facingRight;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every frame, in your `Update()` method, you start the `UpdatePath()` coroutine. Then, in `UpdatePath()`, you start another `UpdatePath()` coroutine. In no situation do you don't start it, so this ensures that `UpdatePath()` keeps running forever and ever.

Since you also keep starting a new one in `Update()`, this means that you keep piling on more and more coroutines, which means the more the game runs, the more `UpdatePath()` gets called every frame.

in other words, your object's speed isn't technically increasing, it's just the number of time `MoveTowards()` is called that does, which does have the same end result.

As for the fix, I'd recommend restructuring your code. For example, I find it highly suspicious that `Update()` and `UpdatePath()` are near identical copies of each other. I also find it weird that `UpdatePath()` starts itself at the end of its run.